# explanations required to understand local eval execution VERSUS remote eval execution

Tags: bash, ssh, eval

Good afternoon community,

I need to exec a set of commands locally and remotely on several servers through ssh.
Today I duplicate the code but to make it more readable I wanted to put the command in a VARIABLE then **eval** it locally and remotely hence remove the code duplicate

The result when eval is run remotely is not working as expected and I'd be happy if anybody explains me what I do wrong

Below is my simple use case

```
# on local server and remote server we have two different files I want to list

# on local server
bash$ ls logs/*fruits
logs/apple.fruits

# on remote server
bash$ ls logs/*fruits
logs/strawberry.fruit

# command to be executed
my_command='for f in $(ls logs/*fruits);do echo $f;done'
echo $my_command
for f in $(ls logs/*fruits);do echo $f;done

# local eval
bash$ eval "$my_command"
logs/apple.fruit

# now let's try the eval remotely
bash$ ssh remoteserver "eval \"$my_command\""

hp617srv autoengine /data/apps/ci/REQ1_UBSCLS_6557_2/app/
bash$ ssh remoteserver "echo \"$my_command\""
for f in logs/strawberry.fruits;do echo ;done
```

I expected the ssh output to be *logs/strawberry.fruits* but it's EMPTY

If I echo my_command **$f** is missing, this could explain the failure

Am i doing anything wrong? do I understand correctly how eval is working?

Thanks for your feedback

Comment: There's no variable `my_command` set on the remote server. Even `ssh remoteserver "echo \"$my_command\""` is taking the contents from your local variable.

Comment: Why would you use eval for this at all? `ssh remoteserver "$my_command"` has the effect you want of running your command remotely. Remember, ssh concatenates its positional arguments into a single string, and runs that string in a remote shell.

Comment: Also, note that `for anything in $(ls ...)` is an antipattern and categorically buggy. Don't parse output of `ls`; see [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) and [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: (Also, storing commands in strings is a bad idea in the first place; the right way to do this is with a function)

Comment: ...that is to say: `my_command() { for f in logs/*fruits; do echo "$f"; done; };` after which you can run `my_command` locally, or `ssh remoteserver "$(declare -f my_command); my_command"` to run it remotely.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for guidance on why putting commands in strings is buggy in general, and [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) for guidance on why `eval` is best avoided in particular.

Comment: Charles, I just want to find a way to remove my duplicate code (x lines executed locally then those x lines are copied in my ssh call).
To all, thanks I'll review your links. Always happy to learn

Comment: All good advice above. As far as *"Explanation required"* ... Learning to debug such issues is your best teacher. Learn how to the read output from including shell debug/trace flags in your cmd line, l.e. `ssh remoteserver "set -vx; echo \"$my_command\" ; set +vx"` will show you the remote execution trace, while `set -vx; ssh remoteserver "echo \"$my_command\"" ; set +vx` shows you what is happening locally. (There's more to it that this (-; but ...). The lines prepended with `+` are the actual command that is executed after all variable and cmd-stutition interpolations have happened. GoodLuck